# Access static member when type and variable has same name

Tags: c#

How do I tell the compiler that the "Thing" in "Thing.VariableProperty" is the type not the instance? Like this it says that my instance of Thing does not contain a definition of VariableProperty.

Or is it wrong of me to use the type name as variable name also?

```cs
  public interface IThing
  {
    int Variable { get; }
  }

  public class Thing : IThing
  {
    public const string VariableProperty = nameof(Variable);

    public int Variable => 1;
  }


  public class MyClass
  {
    public IThing Thing = new Thing();

    public string GiveMeAString()
    {
      return "Something about " + Thing.VariableProperty;
    }
  }
```

Comment: This code already works? https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQBEJinANjASQDsYIFsBjCAgWwAdcIaITYBLAeyIBoYQE4PACYgA1AB8AAgAYABJICMAbgCwAKEkBmeQoBs8gEw6A7LIDe62VfnbF+yQBZZAWShsiACgCU5y9f+KAJweRBAA7i4AngDCuFDIyN4AdADibABuEM4QAIIAyjAI7gDm3l6qav4Avuo1aupahrIAKgAWJeoWlTayFFzIMDpyAGpQRVDAjAAKCBx0ZDCRsgC8skRQzBxgHqPjkxDl6n6N7oO7bBOMK7LKtUcatkbOMXEJncfabSUt7UTF16EIl8/t4Kh8hrI0plsvlCiVvH4ugFTAASABEeQ4zBgv3+Ew4cEGZmBxSS50uEBmcwWkSqaIqVjqVSAA= This is the "Color Color" problem, and C# was specifically designed to permit it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/07/06/color-color/

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen that sounds like an answer, you should write one.

Comment: See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212638/is-it-poor-practice-to-name-a-property-member-the-same-as-the-declaring-type-in/212772#212772

Comment: Please post your actual code. I say this because you have used `@` for string interpolation, which won't work, `{Thing.VariableProperty}` is just text, meaning that not only would you not get a compiler error from this, it wouldn't even print what you wanted it to print. Clearly, this is not the right code. Can you please post your *actual* code so that we're not missing something?

Comment: you can do 'return @"Something about {this.Thing.VariableProperty}";'

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia You can, but a) that still uses a verbatim string rather than an interpolated string, and b) his code works even if you change his verbatim string to an interpolated string, so there's no *need* for `this.`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Sorry! I've fixed the example so that it actually represents my problem.

Comment: You could call your instance "oThing" instead (or indeed anything other than Thing) -  you could probably use the full namespace of the type Thing too, but i'd much prefer not overlapping variables names and typenames.

Comment: The "Color Color" issue is no longer relevant since the C# specification specifically needs the name and the type to be identical. Since IThing is not the same as Thing, the C# specification doesn't say what should happen and this thus falls outside of the specification and isn't handled.

Comment: Specifically, the specification, point 7.6.4.1, Identical Simple Names and Type Names, says this: "In a member access of the form E.I, if E is a single identifier, and if the **meaning of E as a simple-name** (§7.6.2) is a constant, field, property, local variable, or parameter **with the same type as the meaning of E as a type-name** (§3.8), then both possible meanings of E are permitted." (my emphasis) Since `Thing` as a field has the type `IThing` and not `Thing`, this case doesn't fall under this part of the specification.

Comment: Indeed, he has changed his question and this is no longer the "Color Color" problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fully qualified name of the `Test` class, if it is in a namespace, or you can use the [`global`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/global) keyword to refer to the class:

```
...
public string GiveMeAString()
{
    return "Something about " + global::Thing.VariableProperty;
    // Or
    // return "Something about " + My.Namespace.Thing.VariableProperty;
}
...
```

A third way would be to use the [`using static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) directive:

```
using static Thing;

...
public string GiveMeAString()
{
    return "Something about " + VariableProperty;
}
...
```

But in this case i would recommend to either use another name for the `Thing` class like e.g `SpecializedThing` or to rename the `MyClass.Thing` field to e.g. `aThing` or `myThing`.